# Counter error in PHP-MySql

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I made a php-mysql counter for my webpage.

When I add an image from another site to my site, the counter is not working correctly.

For checking the file exist or not on another site I use this code

```
<?php
function load_image($external_path,$internal_path)
{   
    if(@fopen($external_path,"r")==true)
    {
        return $external_path;
    }
    else
    {
        return $internal_path;
    }
}
?>
```

If it not found, then it shows from my site.

But it create a problem in counter.

If I have 4 external image it increase as +4.

The increment code is as follows---

```
<?php
class visitor
{
    function increment()
    {       
        $sql="select count_no from tbl_count"; 
        $result=DBAccess::execute_my_query($sql);
        if ($result!="") 
        {
            $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $visit_no=$rows['count_no'];    
        }   
        else
        {
            $first_visit_no=1;
            $sql1="insert into tbl_count (count_no) values ($first_visit_no)";
            $ins=DBAccess::execute_my_query($sql1);
        }
        $update_visit_no= $visit_no+1;
        $sql2="update tbl_count set count_no=$update_visit_no";
        $ins2=DBAccess::execute_my_query($sql2);                
        return $update_visit_no;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: show us the code which increases the counter, please

Comment: I'm assuming this script generates a path for your counter script to serve up an image? Makes sense it'll increment once for each image served. You'll have to set a cookie on the first image to tell subsequent hits on the counter to NOT increment.

Comment: this is my first post in stackoverflow, can any body help me how i post my code here again in <code> format!

Comment: edit your post, and just start every line of code with at least 4 spaces. don't post code in the comments, it would be unreadable.

Comment: @beerwin I post increment function.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using fopen the browser is doing a http request to the server. So each time you use the function its like opening the page again.

Try [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

It should avoid the count issue you are having.